# Spring view page detail with ajax

Tags: ajax, spring-boot

I would like to know how you would make an ajax call to another page to show a listing containing the service data

Models.html

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">Id</th>
                      <th scope="col">Model</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                        
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

Controller

```
 @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/cars/{id}/model")
    public List<Model> getModels(@PathVariable Long id) {
      Optional<Car> car = carRepository.findById(id);
      return car.get().getModels();
    }
```

Json

```
$('table').on('click', 'button[id="model"]', function(e){
         var id = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
         $.ajax({
             type:"GET",
             enctype: 'application/json',
             url:"/cars/" + id + "/model",
             success: function(data){
                 var models = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                 for (var i in models) {
                     console.log(i);
                 }
             },
             error: function(err) {  
                console.log("Error");
             }
     });
```

Comment: Is something not working in the code shown?

Comment: The code fetches the data perfectly in my API. Only I wanted it to go to another page when I clicked the button
 <td> <button id = 'model' class = 'btn btn-sucess'> Models </button> </td>

Comment: Example I clicked on id 1 the system should open another page with the table populated with the model data according to id

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "wanted it to go to another page"?  If you want the user to navigate to a new page then don't use AJAX.  Just use a link to that page.